# union and intersection

Tags: analysis

Given a,b are real number and a is less than or equal b.
Find the union of $\left[a+\frac{1}{n};b-\frac{1}{n}\right]$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Find the intersection of $\left[a-\frac{1}{n};b+\frac{1}{n}\right]$

I understand that when n is increasing then $a-\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow  a$ and $b+\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow b$ so I think the union must be $[a,b]$.
Can someone please explain clearly so I can understand clearly problem.Thank you

Comment: I think you editted it wrong.  It should be a + (1/n); not (a + 1)/n.

Comment: @fleablood I only edited what OP wrote, I am not allowed to change their formulae, only the format. If you think it is wrong then perhaps you should edit it yourself.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I could edit other people's posts.  Done

If memory serves me right the original post said a + 1/n  which, when written on a single line could be interpreted ambiguously.

Answer (score 2):

Note: if a + 1 >= b - 1.  The interval [a + 1; b - 1] isn't really properly defined.  Make a special case of this.

But assuming a + 1 < b - 1....

Note: that each $[a + \frac{1}{(n+1)}$;$b-\frac{1}{(n+1)}]$ is completely contained in $[a + \frac{1}{n}$;$b-\frac{1}{n}]$.

You are right that $ a + \frac{1}{n}$ approaches a.  So for any  a' > a (assume a' is *very* close to a)  there is some 1/n such that $a  < a + \frac{1}{n} < a'$.  (right?)  So a' is in the union.    *BUT* although a + 1/n approaches a and a is the lim a + 1/n, (right?) a does not ever equal any a + 1/n.  So a is *not* in the union.  But everything slightly above a is.

So [a, b] is not the union because a is not in the union.  But everything slightly above a is.  Similarly b is not in the union but everything slightly smaller than b is.  So the union isn't [a, b] but everything between a and b but not including a and b.

Does that help?

======

More detail.

$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = a  $ means for any $\epsilon$ > 0.  There is some N such that for all n >= N,  $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$.  It's a routine exercise to show the $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0  $.  This means that for any x > 0 we can find an n such that 0 < $\frac{1}{n} $ < x.

And that is *everything*.

For any x>a, we can find an v such that a < a + $\frac{1}{v}$ < x.  If x < b we can find a w such that x < b - $\frac{1}{w}$ < b.  If a < x < b we can find appropriate v and w and we can let n = max(v, w).

Then a < a + $\frac{1}{n}$  <= a +  $\frac{1}{v}$ < x < b - $\frac{1}{w}$ < b - $\frac{1}{n}$ < b.   In other words, if x is in [a + $\frac{1}{n}$, b - $\frac{1}{n}$] for some n.  So x is in the union.  So all (a, b) is in the union.

If x <= a then x <= a < a + $\frac{1}{n}$ for all n, so x is not in any interval.  Same with x>=b.  So x is in the union if and only if x is in (a, b).  So the union is (a, b).

That's union (assuming all a + 1/n <= b - 1/n; i.e. a+ 1 <= b- 1 you'll need to do a special case other wise).

Intersection is done the exact same way but you get a slightly different result.  (Actually Intersection is easier because we don't have to find two simultaneous v and w and take the max.)

If x < a there exists an 1/n such that x < a - 1/n < a. So x is not in [a - 1/n, b + 1/n].  You can take it from there.

Comment: Thank you for verify my mistake of the question. Would you please write it more clearly like use math notation... so I can have better picture.

Comment: Also, for intersection of [a-1/n;b+1/n] is [a,b]? Please guide me understand correctly.thank you for your time and help

Comment: Yes, the intersect is [a, b] (closed) because any x such that a <= x <= b then x is in [a - 1/n, b + 1/n] for all n.  Thus it's in the intersection.  Trick is showing x < a and x > b are not in  [a - 1/n, b + 1/n] for all n.

Comment: if A intersect B is ( a-1/n;b+1/n)     (open interval) then the intersect is empty,is it correct?

Comment: I don't understand.  What are A and B?  No, the intersection of  the open intervals would still be [a, b] for the same reason. (as: [a, b] is a subset of all the open intervals it will be in the intersection; if x is not in [a, b] there will be an intersection which doesn't contain x so only [a,b] can be in the intersection.)  It's interesting as the *finite* intersection of open sets is open, but this is an *infinite* intersection of open sets that is closed.